# Mandate no more/no less than 11 digits in a Mobile Number field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make sure that people enter no less/no more than 11 digits into a field before they can submit a form. Here's the current script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#form_submission_phone_number").keypress(function(e){
  if(this.value.length!=11){
   $('.nom').remove();
      $(this).after('<span class="nom" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000; opacity: 0.6;margin-top: -2px;display: block;">please enter full 11-digit mobile number starting with 1</span>');
  }else{
      $('.nom').remove();
  }
    var keyCode = e.which;
    /*
    8 - (backspace)
    32 - (space)
    48-57 - (0-9)Numbers
    */
    if ( (keyCode != 8 || keyCode ==32 ) && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57)) { 
      return false;
    }
    
    
    
    if(this.value.length==11){
        return false;
    }
  });
   $('#form_submission_phone_number').keyup(function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8)$(this).val('');})  
});
```

Comment: We need your relevant HTML code too.

Comment: Why not just prevent form submission if the length !== 11?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm versed in HTML and CSS, not JS. Trying to figure out a snippet I can insert to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your code. First of all, I moved the part that hides or shows the `span` to the `keyup` listener, because that's when you know the final length of your input. Also, I used `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of removing the element and recreating it each time.

I commented out the final part that caused a backspace to delete the entire input because it seemed unnecessary to me, but you can keep it if you need it. I also slightly changed the `if` statement that decides if a character is accepted or not, so in that case you might want to add `keyCode == 8` to those conditions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#form_submission_phone_number").keypress(function(e) {
    
    var keyCode = e.which;
    /*
    8 - (backspace)
    32 - (space)
    48-57 - (0-9)Numbers
    */
    if ( keyCode == 32 || keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) { 
      return false;
    }

    if (this.value.length == 11) {
      return false;
    }
  });
      
  $('#form_submission_phone_number').keyup(function(e) {
    if (this.value.length != 11) {
      $('.nom').show();
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('.nom').hide();
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    /*if (e.keyCode == 8)
      $(this).val('');
    }*/
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="form_submission_phone_number" /><br>
    <span class="nom" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000; opacity: 0.6;margin-top: -2px;display: block;">please enter full 11-digit mobile number starting with 1</span><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab! Still lets me submit less than 11 and doesn't let me backspace once I've typed in the field.

Comment: I edited my answer, there is now a submit button which is disabled whenever the input length is less than 11. I'm not sure what you mean about the backspace, it seems to work in the snippet.